# Wrong subnet configuration works anyway in a shared bus, but doesn't work in switched lan. Why?

Tags: networking, subnet, ipv4, switching, netmask

I was told that this configuration (which contains an error in DNS mask which is /23 instead of /24) works only because it's a SHARED bus. If it was a SWITCHED lan, the DNS responses from DNS to A wouldn't "be forwarded". Why?

[image]

Basically A, in order to communicate with DNS, has to pass THROUGH the DG (default gateway) because A sees the DNS address in another subnet. On the other hand, the DNS sees A in his same subnet (since IP A is inside DNS /23) so DNS "talks" directly (dest macaddress is A instead of DG so it's a direct communication) with A WITHOUT passing through DG.

I was told that this only works because the lan is a shared bus. If it was a switched lan the DNS response wouldn't be forwarded(????) Why? What does it mean? What's the issue?

Comment: I am not seeing how the statement can be true. A simple/unmanaged switch wouldn't even know whether it's a reply. (But it does need to perform another ARP that is for A's MAC.)

Comment: Btw, forward is not a wrong word to use in an L2/switch context, in case you don't know. It doesn't have a really "special" meaning though, AFAIK. It really just mean sending traffics from one port to another.

Comment: One thing I can think of is that the two hosts can be a different VLANs (or more generally, different broadcast domains), but that doesn't make the statement true. (Some "norm" kind of guy might say something like "when there are two IP subnets, one should assume that each of them is actually used in its own VLAN" though.)

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT [CROSSPOST](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84233/wrong-subnet-configuration-works-anyway-in-a-shared-bus-but-doesnt-work-in-swi)!

Answer (score 2):

> I was told that this only works because the lan is a shared bus. If it was a switched lan

This kind of distinction sounds to me like **old** material from the era when networks like [**ATM**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_Transfer_Mode) were competing with Ethernet, for both LAN and WAN usage. I'm guessing so because modern Ethernet isn't a shared bus anymore (it's switched), but *a few decades ago* it was – in contrast to networks such as ATM that were packet-switched from the beginning. I've seen marketing material use it as a bullet point in praising ATM's "superiority over legacy Ethernet".

(ATM didn't last long, though you can see some of its influences in IPv6 – such as the way IPv6 addresses were formatted, with a fixed-length, MAC-address-based suffix.)

One thing about ATM was that it integrated the link layer and network layer into a single unit, so every ATM 'switch' was closer to what you'd now call a router, and there was no real difference between "local subnet" and "non-local" traffic – both went through the switch(/router) in the same way.

In addition, ATM was a "virtual circuit"-based technology that did not support broadcast, so if you were to set up IP-based "LAN emulation" on top of an ATM-based LAN, you *wouldn't* be able to broadcast an ARP query in a way that could be seen by hosts in another "subnet" – you would have a dedicated "[LAN Emulation Server](https://www.novell.com/it-it/documentation/nias42/itcomm/rtcn_ita/data/hbvplq2e.html)" (probably the ATM router/switch itself) to handle the equivalent of ARP. So it's possible that a LES would keep isolated lists of IPs/MACs for each subnet that it manages and wouldn't be able to respond to the example DNS server's query for a L2 address belonging to an out-of-subnet IP address.

So if the book compares "shared bus" with "switched" LAN, it really sounds to me that it's comparing historic Ethernet with ATM or something similar – none of it applies to modern switched Ethernet because it still uses broadcast ARP as before, so the misconfigured host *would* still be able to respond.

Comment: There's no hint to any ATM reference in the diagram or the question. Actually, it's all about IPv4, and it's totally working there, no matter whether it's a shared cable, repeated Ethernet (w/ hub) or switched. See https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84233/wrong-subnet-configuration-works-anyway-in-a-shared-bus-but-doesnt-work-in-swi.

Comment: @Zac67: "Switched LAN" in contrast to "Ethernet LAN" seems a pretty strong hint to me. I think that's kind of the whole point of OP's question – either their study material is outright wrong in talking about switched Ethernet LANs, or it is referencing something that it doesn't _explicitly_ mention but certainly is some sort of a non-Ethernet-based LAN. I'm strongly leaning towards the latter.

Comment: Before Ethernet was commonly switched, a "switched LAN" would rather be built on FDDI instead of ATM. With FDDI, the same logic applies as with Ethernet: it works either way. It's only when there's no clean division between layer 2 and 3 that this setup breaks down.